# Freemember Radio Buttons clear on inline errors

Tags: freemember

I have a member registration page that uses custom fields with freemember.
E.g.

```
{exp:freemember:register
            form_name="co-marketing_apply"
            return="/apply/thank-you"
            error_handling="inline"
            error_delimiters='<span class="Apply-formError">|</span>'
            require="email|member-address-1|member-first-name|member-last-name|member-city|member-state|member-zip|member-phone|member-company|order-volume"}

<input type="radio" name="order-volume" value="200 Pounds">200 Pounds
<input type="radio" name="order-volume" value="50 Pounds">50 pounds
```

The registration works fine, but I need some help dealing with error messages.

Problem 1: If there are ANY inline errors returned, the radio buttons are cleared out. Meaning the user has to fill out all of them again.

Problem 2: I need custom error messages because certain radio buttons, if checked, will disqualify the user from applying.